# There is no template at <Template Path URL> error in ejs.js

Tags: javascript, templates, ejs, web-config

I was trying to setup the sample project for ejs (embedded js), given on their website homepage (http://embeddedjs.com/) in my typescript project.

I received the error `There is no template at templates/supplies.ejs.` But the path is there, the template is in `templates/supplies.ejs` why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mime type into the web.config file like this

```
 <system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".ejs" mimeType="text/plain" />
   </staticContent>
 </system.webServer>
```

into the `<configuration>` element in your web.config file.

Comment: Do you know what the apache setting would be?